# SQL Running Total Grouped by Date

Tags: sql-server-2008, count

(Using SQL Server 2008) I could easily get this to work if I built a view, and then a query on the view, but I want to perform this in one SQL query. I have a table that contains two columns (DeliveredDate (DateTime), Delivered (Varchar)).  I am first converting DeliveredDate to Date only, and then grouping by Date. At the same time I am performing a Count on Delivered (column is either YES or NULL). Here is what I use to accomplish this portion:

```
  SELECT CAST([DeliveredDate] As Date),
         COUNT([Delivered])
  FROM [TableName]
  GROUP BY CAST([DeliveredDate] As Date)
  ORDER BY CAST([DeliveredDate] As Date)
```

As an output, I get something like:

```
DeliveredDate  |  Delivered
 2012-04-24          10
 2012-04-25         500
 2012-04-26         422
 2012-04-27          33
```

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
DeliveredDate  |  Delivered  |  RunningTotal
 2012-04-24          10            10
 2012-04-25         500           510
 2012-04-26         422           932
 2012-04-27          33           965
```

I've tried various examples I've seen out there, but none seem to match this scenario of performing a Count and a RunningTotal on said Count.

Comment: It's helpful to say which RDBMS you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if a CTE counts as a view but this will work in SQL 2005+ which Does Not Support ordered OVER clauses for SUM,

```
WITH cte (DeliveredDate, Delivered)
     AS (SELECT Cast([DeliveredDate] AS DATE) DeliveredDate, 
                Count([Delivered]) Delivered 
         FROM   [TableName] 
         GROUP  BY Cast([DeliveredDate] AS DATE)) 
SELECT d1.delivereddate, 
       d1.delivered, 
       Sum(d2.Delivered) RunningTotal 
FROM   cte d1 
       LEFT JOIN cte d2 
         ON d1.delivereddate >= d2.DeliveredDate 
GROUP  BY d1.delivereddate, 
          d1.delivered 
ORDER BY d1.delivereddate
```

Comment: There's something wrong with this code, but I like where you are going. I think there's supposed to be a space between cte and d1, and then I think the second Group By is supposed to be Order By?  When I run this, I get "No column name was specified for column 1 of 'cte'"

Comment: @JasonH doh sorry about that. I was more concerned about [testing the running total](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0eae2/3) and I messed up putting in the CTE. It should be all fixed up now

Comment: Thanks a lot, seriously, racked my brain on this one all yesterday

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a product that implements ordered OVER clauses for SUM, you can do something like this:

```
select
  cast(DeliveredDate as date) as DeliveredDate,
  count(Delivered) as Delivered,
  sum(count(Delivered)) over (
    order by DeliveredDate
  ) as RunningTotal
from Orders
group by OrderDate
order by OrderDate;
```

Your expression count(Delivered) is a bit strange. Just to be sure it's what you want: it will count the number of rows on the particular date for which the value in the Delivered column is NOT NULL.

Comment: This answer does not work in my situation, I don't believe over is supported in the version of SQL I'm working with.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 supports `OVER` but I don't think it supports `ORDER BY` within an `OVER` for an aggregate function.

Comment: SQL Server supports this as of SQL Server 2012 only.