# MS Access - running 12-month total

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to calculate a 12-month running total in MS Access. In Oracle SQL I would achieve this using a window function like

```
SELECT date, SUM(salesvol) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS 11 PRECEDING) AS running_tot FROM table1
```

but apparently MS Access does not support window functions. My initial thought was to write a query using the datediff function, but because my date variable is in the varchar format, I don't think this is a practical way to go.

My dataset consists of two columns: date (VARCHAR) and salesvol (NUMBER):

```
date    salesvol
200901  473560 
200902  426204 
200903  473560 
200904  662984 
200905  473560 
200906  662984 
200907  615628 
200908  236780 
200909  426204 
200910  331492 
200911  426204 
200912  378848 
201001  236780 
201002  426204 
201003  426204 
201004  142068 
201005  426204 
201006  520916 
201007  568272 
201008  520916 
201009  520916 
201010  520916 
201011  568272 
201012  947120
```

My desired output is this:

```
date    salesvol     running_tot 
200901  473560  473560
200902  426204  899764
200903  473560  1373324
200904  662984  2036308
200905  473560  2509868
200906  662984  3172852
200907  615628  3788480
200908  236780  4025260
200909  426204  4451464
200910  331492  4782956
200911  426204  5209160
200912  378848  5588008
201001  236780  5351228
201002  426204  5351228
201003  426204  5303872
201004  142068  4782956
201005  426204  4735600
201006  520916  4593532
201007  568272  4546176
201008  520916  4830312
201009  520916  4925024
201010  520916  5114448
201011  568272  5256516
201012  947120  5824788
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the varchar date to DATE format. You can use dates as the 1st day of the month. Refer the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359395/how-to-convert-a-text-field-to-a-date-time-field-in-access-2010) for conversion.

Then you can refer for the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450425/sql-running-total-grouped-by-date) for Running total.

Comment: I guess you missed this is for Access.

Comment: You can convert to Date using this expression: `CDate(Format("200910", "@@@@/@@"))` but actually you wouldn't need that, as strings like  "200910" etc. are perfectly sortable _as is_.